# How can unconditional branches be predicted with a 2-bit predictor?

Tags: assembly, branch, cpu, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I found:

> (Sandy Bridge)
>
> Pattern recognition for indirect jumps and calls
>
> Indirect jumps and indirect calls (but not returns) are predicted
>   **using the same two-level predictor as branch instructions**.

here on page 27:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

I do not understand how conditional and unconditional branches can both use a 2-bit predictor? I thought unconditional branches would use a Branch Target Buffer (BTB). How can unconditional branches be predicted using a 2-bit predictor?!

Could somebody please explain, say for a recent Intel CPU, how the branch prediction works for conditional and unconditional branches with regards to predictors, history tables and BTB caches? I am uncertain if they work together, for both types of branches, or they both exist but only handle different branch types??

Comment: http://www.anandtech.com/show/3922/intels-sandy-bridge-architecture-exposed/2 . Also - 2-level != 2-bit, and uncoditional != indirect

Comment: @Leeor Sorry, I meant conditional and indirect. Regarding the link you sent me, how do the BTB and BHT interact together? I thought BTB is used immediately to determine whether the instruction is a branch/return the branch address and then the BHT is used to decide whether to actually branch there, or next fetch PC+4? Your link seems to suggest instructions are split in to conditional/indirect, conditional use the BHT and indirect use the BTB?

Comment: You actually have all 4 combinations of {direct,indirect} x {conditional, unconditional}, indirect ones need a target prediction, conditional ones need an outcome prediction, and a combination of those require both predictions. There's some more about this in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787457/branch-target-prediction-in-conjunction-with-branch-prediction